# GROUP BY not for empty strings

Tags: mariadb, group-by

I would like to group by `email`. Sometimes `email` is missing in records, which then should not be grouped.

How can I create an exception for empty strings when grouping?

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fullname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  something VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO example (id, fullname, email, something) VALUES
  (1, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 1'),
  (2, 'Name 2', '', 'Something 2'),
  (3, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 3'),
  (4, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 4'),
  (5, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 5'),
  (6, 'Name 4', '', 'Something 6');
```

As a result, I would like:

```
SELECT fullname, email FROM example GROUP BY email [...];
+----------+-------------------+
| fullname | email             |
+----------+-------------------+
| Name 2   |                   |
| Name 4   |                   |
| Name 1   | name1@example.com |
| Name 3   | name3@example.com |
+----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is it empty string or null you want to exclude? For null `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE email is not null GROUP BY email`. Beware that older versions of MySQL allow partial group by that may lead to in-deterministic results.

Comment: Empty string. But I want the records with the empty strings to be included in the result.

Comment: Why don't you just `group by fullname, email` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION and use it to get the wanted result.

Instead of WHERE email = '' you can use WHERE email IS NULL, if the column doesn't have '' as text

> ```
> CREATE TABLE example (
>   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT Primary KEY,
>   fullname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>   email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>   something VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO example (id, fullname, email, something) VALUES
>   (1, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 1'),
>   (2, 'Name 2', '', 'Something 2'),
>   (3, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 3'),
>   (4, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 4'),
>   (5, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 5'),
>   (6, 'Name 4', '', 'Something 6');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fullname), email 
> FROM example 
> WHERE email <> ''
> GROUP BY email 
> UNION
> SELECT fullname, email 
> FROM example 
> WHERE email = ''
> ORDER BY email;
> ```
>
> ```
> GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fullname) | email            
> :------------------------------ | :----------------
> Name 2                          |                  
> Name 4                          |                  
> Name 1                          | name1@example.com
> Name 3                          | name3@example.com
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fullname), email 
> FROM example 
> GROUP BY email
> ```
>
> ```
> GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fullname) | email            
> :------------------------------ | :----------------
> Name 2,Name 4                   |                  
> Name 1                          | name1@example.com
> Name 3                          | name3@example.com
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad0f011f6ebd87d26ef889001016a695)*